# Close Python IDLE shell without prompt

Tags: python-2.7, python-idle

I am working on a script (script A), that needs to open a new Python IDLE shell, automatically run another script (script B) in it and then close it. The following code is what I use for this purpose:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['','-n','-t','My New Shell','-c','execfile("VarLoader.py")']
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

However I can't get the new shell close automatically. I have tried adding the following to script B but either it doesn't close the new shell or a windows pops up asking whether I want to kill it.

```
exit()
```

.

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you are able to get the process id, you can send `kill -15` to it

Comment: *"that needs to open a new Python IDLE shell, automatically run another script (script B) in it and then close it"* - could you elaborate on why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am using an engineering software capable of running python scripts internally. Sometimes, this software acts strange with Python scripts; all of a sudden and out of nowhere it stops working. Thus, it needs debugging frequently. However, the software doesn't provide a python shell. Accordingly, I have to cheat a bit and open an IDLE which runs my script!

Comment: Any way you look at it you need to change the default behaviour of `idlelib.PyShell.PyShell.close` which is responsible for that prompt, prehaps with a subclass but then you would need to implement your own `main` instead of using the default (or monkeypatch which I do not recommend for this)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks for your suggestion, I looked at idlelib.PyShell and entered response = "True" instead of the window propt. The problem was solved. They should possibly include a flag/arg for this purpose in the next version of Python27

Comment: you... edited the source? Oh dear, so you want to omit every prompt to exit while using IDLE?  I will post an answer as an alternative that does not require changing how IDLE works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of monkeypatching or modifying the IDLE source code to make your program skip the prompt to exit I'd recommend you create a subclass of `PyShell` that overrides the `close` method how you want it to work:

```
import idlelib.PyShell
class PyShell_NoExitPrompt(idlelib.PyShell.PyShell):
    def close(self):
        "Extend EditorWindow.close(), does not prompt to exit"
##        if self.executing:
##            response = tkMessageBox.askokcancel(
##                "Kill?",
##                "Your program is still running!\n Do you want to kill it?",
##                default="ok",
##                parent=self.text)
##            if response is False:
##                return "cancel"
        self.stop_readline()
        self.canceled = True
        self.closing = True
        return idlelib.PyShell.EditorWindow.close(self)
```

The original issue with this was that then using `idlelib.PyShell.main` would not use your subclass, you can in fact create a **copy** of the function - without modifying the original - by using the `FunctionType` constructor that will use your modified class:

```
import functools
from types import FunctionType

def copy_function(f, namespace_override):
    """creates a copy of a function (code, signature, defaults) with a modified global scope"""
    namespace = dict(f.__globals__)
    namespace.update(namespace_override)
    new_f = FunctionType(f.__code__, namespace, f.__name__, f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
    return functools.update_wrapper(f, new_f)
```

Then you can run your extra IDLE shell like this:

```
import sys
#there is also a way to prevent the need to override sys.argv but that isn't as concerning to me.
sys.argv = ['','-n','-t','My New Shell','-c','execfile("VarLoader.py")']
hacked_main = copy_function(idlelib.PyShell.main,
                            {"PyShell":PyShell_NoExitPrompt})

hacked_main()
```

Now you can leave IDLE the way it is and have your program work the way you want it too. (it is also compatible with other versions of python!)