# How do I get rid of the ' the program is still running are you sure you want to kill it' warning on python?

Tags: python, python-idle

```
print ('Password Request Initiative')

password = 'abcd'
user_input = input('Please Enter Password: ')

if user_input != password:
    print("Haha. Nope") 
    quit()

elif user_input == password:
            print ("User is now logged in...")
    enter code here
```

that's the code, but when I run it and type the wrong password it shows this warning:[And I want it to run without this message so it just instantly closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1X3F.png)

Comment: What happens if you change `quit()` to `exit()` or `sys.exit()`? You need to `import sys` first to make that last one work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used

Comment: I don't get when message when trying to `quit()`. **How** are you running that code?

Comment: Those solutions aren't what the person is looking for. The intended solution is for the Python shell to close upon exit, but without a prompt as called by `exit()` or `quit()`.

Comment: closely related to [Close Python IDLE shell without prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839234/close-python-idle-shell-without-prompt/37841282#37841282) Although that person was creating the idle shell manually in their code.

Comment: Is quit() method defined with proper exit? May be a long running process inside quit would be preventing the program to terminate!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the message when running from IDLE, do not use `quit()` or `exit()` in a program.  They are not part of the language and are not intended for this use.  They are (usually) added by the site package for [interactive use only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit). In particular, they were added so that people could more easily exit the interactive interpreter when running in a terminal window -- without knowing the magic control code needed on a particular system -- and without closing the terminal window itself.

```
C:\Users\Terry>python
Python 3.5.1 ... [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ^Z
C:\Users\Terry>python
```

On Unix, `^D`, End of File, exits, but on DOS and still on Windows, `^Z<Return>` is used instead.  Few beginners know this.  Other interactive programs use `quit` and `exit`, so we added those as synonyms.

With IDLE, `^D` in the shell closes the shell on all systems, but not editor windows.  It is the same as clicking the close button on the title bar.  At least on Windows, `^Q` == `quit()` and closes everything.

To exit a program when not as the bottom of a file, use `raise SystemExit` or `sys.exit()`.

As the expansion of the acronym says, IDLE is a *development* environment.  It is a feature of IDLE that testing a program within IDLE does not kill IDLE itself, at least not without warning.