# using quit(), exit(), ETC. says "The program is still running, do you want to kill it?"

Tags: python

While making an HTML help tool in Python, I wanted to exit the program smoothly, like clicking the X button on Google Chrome. But, I encountered an issue. It asks me if I want to kill the program, instead of doing it automatically.

I tried using `quit()`, `exit()` and `sys.exit()`. All do the same thing. How can I get the program to exit smoothly?

Comment: Hello. Please show what you tried.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: took a look at the other answers on stack overflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028151/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-the-program-is-still-running-are-you-sure-you-want-to e.g. maybe this makes it clear to you. quit and exit are not to use. and with sys.exit() the message only appears in the idle I guess

Comment: print("Sorry, I didn't catch that..")
print("-----YOU HAVE NO TOKENS LEFT-----")
print("SHUTTING DOWN...")
time.sleep(2)
quit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comments, your problem should only be noticed inside Python's IDLE, but should run just fine when executed inside a terminal. However, this code should also kill your program in IDLE:

```
import os, signal
from time import sleep

print("I will sleep for 3 secs and shut down!")
sleep(3)

os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

This sends a signal to your application to terminate.

Or alternatively you could call `os`' `_exit` function.
From the docs:

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

Comment: It worked! Although on the version I am using, there is no module named "sleep", I had to use `import time` and the command I had to use was `time.sleep(3)`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: if it worked, accept the answer by clicking the gray tick placed right below the arrow pointing down next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I took a different way.
It might be a dirty way of doing it. I don't like the accepted
answer because you have to hardcode those lines in every script.
I just comment out the lines, so that the dialog never shows on screen.

You can find the file /usr/lib/python3.9/idlelib/pyshell.py
aprx: line 1007

```
def close(self):
    "Extend EditorWindow.close()"
    #if self.executing:
        #response = messagebox.askokcancel(
            #"Kill?",
            #"Your program is still running!\n Do you want to kill it?",
            #default="ok",
            #parent=self.text)
        #if response is False:
            #return "cancel"
    self.stop_readline()
    self.canceled = True
    self.closing = True
    return EditorWindow.close(self)
```

That way it will never ask you this silly question "Your program is still running!\n Do you want to kill it?"