# How to stop multiple threads python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have 2 threads in my program that I wish to stop on keyboard interrupt but I dont know how to do it. One of the threads has a while loop and the other is just a function which calls a class full of functions. Please help thank you.

Stopping the program

Comment: You can use a thread to wait for the user to input some value to break the threads. Look at [How to stop a thread in Python](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-stop-thread/).

Comment: I made [some code](https://textdoc.co/1pjxQGsSLmtAKdIZ) to demonstrate how this can be done. It's based on the link I used in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it worked perfectly fine with two threads but with the other thread its not working, when i type exit its stops two and starts the other. Can i put 3 threads in that please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it's simple you have only to kill thread

```
#Start a new thread
t = multiprocessing.Process(target = func)
t.start()
#Kill the thread
t.kill()
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response, currently I am using the threadding module not the processing module, but i still tried it and when i ran the program it said would you  like to kill the program

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyboardInterrupt to catch CTRL+C input and do kill threads.

```
t = None
try:
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target = func)
    t.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    t.kill()
    print("stopping")
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response, I have just tried that right now and the program automatically says "Your program is still Running! Do you want to kill it?" exactly when I press the run button

Comment: @AndreaGatt does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039560/using-quit-exit-etc-says-the-program-is-still-running-do-you-want-to-ki) help?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this logic for standard thread canceling:

**1. MainThread**

- I run input from keyboard in main process/thread
- I can setup event via threading.Event().set()
- See code sample for `class MainThread(threading.Thread)`

> ```
> def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
>     super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>     self._stop_event = threading.Event()
>
> def stop(self):
>     self._stop_event.set()
>
> def stopped(self):
>     return self._stop_event.is_set()
> ```

**2. BackgroudThreads**

- Background threads are checking (periodically) this signal state and can close their execution.

BTW: nice clarification see [article](https://superfastpython.com/kill-a-thread-in-python/)